# Given a directory's DocumentFile, how can one list all images in the directory using MediaStore?

Tags: android

Can't figure it out. Is it possible to query `MediaStore` based on the `Uri` from `DocumentFile`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to query MediaStore based on the Uri from DocumentFile?

Not directly and not for a directory. You can use `listFiles()` on the `DocumentFile` to list its contents, and use `getType()` on each of those to find those with `audio/` MIME types.

If you had a `DocumentFile` for an individual piece of media, on Android 10+ you can get a media `Uri` for it from [`MediaStore.getMediaUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore?hl=en#getMediaUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)). That you could then use to query relevant columns for that individual piece of media.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would be in such case the "proper" way to implement the scenario in which user selects a directory and application loads all the media (e.g. images) in it? Recursively checking `listFiles()` would be very slow for large directories.

Comment: @Siegmeyer: On Android 10+, that scenario is going to suck. You might consider not using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, and instead querying `MediaStore` for the `RELATIVE_PATH` values. Then, net that down to a distinct roster (e.g., `HashSet`) and create your own UI to let the user choose a `RELATIVE_PATH` value. You can then query `MediaStore` for all the media with that `RELATIVE_PATH`. I have not tried this, so I cannot guarantee it will be practical, but it is what I would try if I were in your position.

Comment: What a headache. Probably a good idea to see how open-source gallery apps do this. Again, thanks for the info!